# Set focus on input field after animated scroll iphone/ipad

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, ios, ipad

I'm trying to set focus on an input field after a scroll event inside a click function. But it doesn't work on iphone/ipad and I can't understand why.

```
$('.scroll').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#footer').offset().top
    }, 400, function () {
        $('#footer').find('input').first().focus();
    });
});
```

Comment: Firstly, i think you want: `$('html, body')` not `$('html body')` which would animate only body. Secondly, is the click event fired or not?

Comment: Yes, you have right. Now I have changed that, but it still doesn't work on iphone/ipad. The click event fires but the focus event doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure you can bring focus to specific element on iphone and unfortunately, i cannot test it. Maybe by delaying the focus: `$('#footer').find('input').first().stop().delay(500).queue(function(){$(this).focus();})`

Comment: I tried your your code but it didn't work. It's working fine if I'm using the focus event without the animation function, but when I have the focus event inside the animation callback it doesn't work.

Comment: But is the animation callback called?

Comment: I have an anonymous function in the animation callback. function () {
        $('#footer').find('input').first().focus();
    }

Comment: Ya, but my question is if this is called or not?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. The anonymous function is automatically called after the animation?